# Как добавить обработку нажатия на 2D фигуру?

Tags: java

В экземпляре класса `Ellipse2D ellipse2D = new Ellipse2D;` метода, обрабатывающего нажатия на фигуру, я не нашла.

Как обработать нажатие на фигуру?

Comment: Что такое нажатие на фигуру? В контексте какого UI вы его применяете?

Answer (score 0):

Вы обрабатываете нажатие мышки методом, в котором проверяете, содержится ли точка в эллипсе.

```
if (ellipse2D.contains(координаты мышки))...
```

Comment: Спасибо я пока-что не знаю сработает или нет. Hо заранее огромное спасибо.Правку вопроса сделаю после того как увижу что работает.Ещё раз заранее огромное спасибо))